# Observer design not working

Tags: java, observers

I am trying to realize an Observer-Pattern in Java.

I have the class `PlannerView extends Observer` which has the following nested class

```
public class TitleInformer extends Observable {
    private String title = "";

    public void SetTitle(String s) {
        title = s;
        this.notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

When I construct the `PlannerView` class, I initialize the observable like this

```
public PlannerView(ProjectController projectController) {

    titleInformer = new TitleInformer();
    titleInformer.addObserver(this);
}
```

Now, I pass my observable `titleInformer` to another objects I create in the `PlannerView` class

```
actionView = new ActionView (titleInformer);
```

The other class `actionView`, which now has the observable referenced like this

```
public ActionView(TitleInformer ti) {
    this.titleInformer = ti;
}
```

calls the method of the observable this way

```
titleInformer.SetTitle("New Project");
```

But back in the `PlannerView`, where the nested Observable is, this last method doesn't get called

```
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    System.out.println(1);
}
```

Why?

Comment: Didn't look at all your code, but why is the PlannerView constructor ignoring its ProjectController parameter?

Comment: I cut it out to make it more readable

Comment: Then remove the parameter altogether. Otherwise it makes me look for it gives a red hearing that has me looking at it as a possible cause for your problem.

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to indicate that changes were made before notifying the observers.

```
public void SetTitle(String s) {
    title = s;
    this.setChanged(); // first
    this.notifyObservers();
}
```

As the [`notifyObservers()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#notifyObservers%28%29) method javadoc states

> **If this object has changed, as indicated by the `hasChanged` method**,
>   then notify all of its observers and then call the clearChanged method
>   to indicate that this object has no longer changed.

This `hasChanged` property is set by the [`setChanged`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html#setChanged%28%29) method.